# Ambiguous Without More Context Error in Parse Query

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform, back4app

I’m experimenting with Parse in a swift app and running through some of the examples but I can’t get the query to run. I’m getting the “ambiguous without more context” error in XCode. Here’s the code:

```
  var query = PFQuery(className: "MyFirstClass")
        query.getObjectInBackground(withId: "Jl0SUJWCQg") {
          (myFirstClass: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
          if error == nil && myFirstClass != nil {
            print(myFirstClass)
          } else {
            print(error)
          }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please point out the line which is firing the error and also share the complete error stack?

Comment: the line firing the error is "query.getObjectInBackground(withId: "Jl0SUJWCQg") " and the error is : "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" - It's a compiler error and won't build.

Comment: Try with `error: Error?` instead of `error: NSError?`